# How to include "use client" in Client and Server Components

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I've got this code in Next JS app tienda **slash** url **slash** guitarra.js and page.js

ASUS@MacBook-Pro-de-Juan app % cd tienda
ASUS@MacBook-Pro-de-Juan tienda % tree

ASUS@MacBook-Pro-de-Juan tienda % tree
tienda
url
guitarra.js
page.js
page.js

2 directories, 3 files

I've got this code in page.js

```
"use client"
import {useState} from "react";
import styles from "@/styles/guitarras.module.css";
import Image from "next/image";

export default async function Producto({params}) {
    "use client"
    const [cantidad, setCantidad] = useState(0)
    const {url}=params;
    const guitarra = await getGuitarra(url)
    const {descripcion, nombre,precio, imagen} = guitarra[0].attributes;
    return(
        <div className={styles.guitarra}>
            <Image src={imagen.data.attributes.url} width={600} height={400} alt={`Imagen de la guitarra ${nombre}`} />
            <div className={styles.contenido}>
                <h3>{nombre}</h3>
                <p className={styles.descripcion}>{descripcion}</p>
                <p className={styles.precio}>{precio}</p>
                <form className={styles.formulario}>
                    <label htmlFor={"cantidad"} >Canitdad</label>
                    <select name={""} id={"cantidad"}>
                        onChange ={e => setCantidad(e.target.value)}
                        <option value={0}>--Selecciona--</option>
                        <option value={1}>1</option>
                        <option value={2}>2</option>
                        <option value={3}>3</option>
                        <option value={4}>4</option>
                        <option value={5}>5</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type={"submit"} value={"Agregar al carrito"}/>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}


export async function generateStaticParams(){
    const respuesta= await fetch('http://localhost:1337/api/guitarras');
    const {data} = await respuesta.json();

    return data.map((guitarra) => ({
        url : guitarra.attributes.url,
    }))
}

async function getGuitarra(url) {
    const respuesta = await fetch(`http://localhost:1337/api/guitarras?filters[url]=${url}&populate=imagen`)
    const {data} = await  respuesta.json();
    return data;
}
```

It worked ok until I included the useState component from React. It seem that you can't combine Client with Server Components in Next JS. I've read about how to fix this problem, because the error message displayed is " Server Error Error: Page "/tienda/[url]/page" cannot use both "use client" and export function "generateStaticParams()". "
As I've said, I've read about how to fix it, and one of the answers is to separate Client from Server and include Client into Server, that's why I've created the file guitarra.js; to include server configuration in this file. But I don't know how to do this. Please anyone know how to resolve this?

This is what I tried
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JE2E3.png)

But it still saying
ReactServerComponentsError:

You're importing a component that needs useState. It only works in a Client Component but none of its parents are marked with "use client", so they're Server Components by default.
Learn more: https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials

This is what I've tried
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2t0tG.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need to separate the ClientComponent from ServerComponent. In the server component I get the information from the API ( I mean, the info of guitarra). And in the ClientComponent, I show that info. 
I need to separate because generateStaticParams() and and useState can't be in the same file.